# OpenJDK 17 GA Release in IntelliJ: Why no v17 language level? Only "X - Experimental Features"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lts

I just downloaded the Oracle OpenJDK 17 GA LTS release and installed it into IntelliJ. I've selected the jdk v17 as my Project SDK and am attempting to set my project language level also to v17, but the only choices are version 1.3 thru 16, along with an SDK Default of "X - Experimental Features". Where is language level version 17?

[image]

Comment: What is the version of your intellij?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ are you using? As far as I remember the language level version 17 was only added in the latest (2021.2) version

Answer (score 8):

Basic support for Java 17 is available in [IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/08/intellij-idea-2021-2-1/)

Answer (score 3):

Should have realized this sooner, but it turns out that the language level in IntelliJ is a function of the actual language support that the current version of IntelliJ has built in and does not come from the JDK. My IntelliJ version was 2021.1.3. I upgraded to 2021.2.1 and the basic 17 language support appeared. More JDK 17 support to be added later per [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/09/java-17-and-intellij-idea/) on *The IntelliJ IDEA Blog*.